# How can you group them in 5 minute increments?

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `device_gimac1000` (
    `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `s_id` MEDIUMINT(9) NOT NULL,
    `ctime` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `a16` FLOAT(12) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `s_id` (`s_id`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `ctime` (`ctime`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=1340374
;
```

```
ID          s_id          ctime                 a16
"1340961"   "430"   "2020-11-26 10:00:30"   "248540000"
"1340948"   "430"   "2020-11-26 10:00:19"   "248539000"
"1340931"   "430"   "2020-11-26 10:00:07"   "248537000"
"1340916"   "430"   "2020-11-26 09:59:56"   "248536000"
"1340902"   "430"   "2020-11-26 09:59:45"   "248535000"
"1340886"   "430"   "2020-11-26 09:59:33"   "248534000"
"1340872"   "430"   "2020-11-26 09:59:21"   "248533000"
"1340856"   "430"   "2020-11-26 09:59:10"   "248532000"
"1340840"   "430"   "2020-11-26 09:58:58"   "248531000"
"1340825"   "430"   "2020-11-26 09:58:47"   "248529000"
"1340809"   "430"   "2020-11-26 09:58:35"   "248528000"
"1340796"   "430"   "2020-11-26 09:58:24"   "248527000"
"1340780"   "430"   "2020-11-26 09:58:13"   "248526000"
"1340767"   "430"   "2020-11-26 09:58:02"   "248525000"
"1340751"   "430"   "2020-11-26 09:57:50"   "248524000"
"1340734"   "430"   "2020-11-26 09:57:39"   "248523000"
"1340721"   "430"   "2020-11-26 09:57:28"   "248522000"
"1340706"   "430"   "2020-11-26 09:57:16"   "248520000"
"1340691"   "430"   "2020-11-26 09:57:05"   "248519000"
"1340674"   "430"   "2020-11-26 09:56:53"   "248518000"
"1340660"   "430"   "2020-11-26 09:56:42"   "248517000"
"1340646"   "430"   "2020-11-26 09:56:30"   "248516000"
"1340629"   "430"   "2020-11-26 09:56:19"   "248515000"
"1340615"   "430"   "2020-11-26 09:56:08"   "248514000"
"1340600"   "430"   "2020-11-26 09:55:56"   "248513000"
"1340585"   "430"   "2020-11-26 09:55:45"   "248512000"
"1340570"   "430"   "2020-11-26 09:55:34"   "248510000"
"1340555"   "430"   "2020-11-26 09:55:22"   "248509000"
"1340540"   "430"   "2020-11-26 09:55:11"   "248508000"
"1340526"   "430"   "2020-11-26 09:55:00"   "248507000"
```

There is a table that has this shape.
In the table, values ​​are entered for each s_id every 10 to 15 seconds.
The value is constantly increasing.
For example, if I want to know the usage of'today', I must subtract the last input value from the value entered around 00:00:02 to become the usage.
Running a query that calculates and subtracts the value for the minimum time and the maximum time respectively is too slow.
So, I am trying to create an aggregate table, but after extracting the maximum value in 5 minutes increments from the above table structure, what do I need to do to get the desired result?

*
It will be operated every five minutes.
*

I want result
[image]

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way:

```
GROUP BY FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ctime) / 3600)
```

Answer (score 0):

Advisory answer. Solved it.
Thank you. I hope it helps others.

```
SELECT
CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(ctime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:'), LPAD(FLOOR(MINUTE(ctime) / 5) * 5, 2, '0'), ':00') timekey,
     #FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ctime)/(5 * 60)) AS timekey,
     s_id,
    max(a16)-MIN(a16)
FROM device_gimac1000
WHERE ctime >= '2020-11-26' AND ctime < '2020-11-27'
GROUP BY timekey,s_id;
```